# Devise notification email not received via devise_async gem and resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque, devise-async

I am using devise_async gem with resque for send email notification in background .

What i did is -   installing devise_async and resque gem.

adding devise_async.rb in initializer with there lines -

```
Devise::Async.enabled = true # | false
Devise::Async.backend = :resque
```

In User model added :async .

when user signs up the notification email is kicked off in backgroung  but not recieved on gmail .

Comment: See my answer - if you've already started a resque worker, let me know and I'll modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to start a Resque worker.  If you're trying this locally, in a new terminal window within your app root directory, run:

```
bundle exec rake resque:work  # resque 2.x
```

or

```
bundle exec rake resque:worker  # resque 1.x
```